# Create database in mysql with golang

Tags: mysql, database, go

I have a code that should create automatically database and table in mysql if they are not exist.

I can create table if I have DB, but I cannot create DB, because in connection string I should provide dbname.

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@tcp(localhost:3306)/dbname?charset=utf8")
```

Is it possible to do it with sql package?

Comment: Thx so much for link. I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just omit the database name from the url, and run a `CREATE` query. After that you can open a connection to your database.